# The Arduino Sketch does not save in Arduino folder location

Tags: arduino-ide, sketch, mac-os

I have just installed Arduino on Mac OS. The Arduino folder is created under Documents. But whenever I save the sketch it gets stored in some ghost location and gives an error, the same name already exits. Upon finding the location of file. It gets stored under this directory(Hidden).

```
/private/var/folders/_v/nbrwcsh51wd2k07kfhy9vhjm0000gn/T/untitled1010592992.tmp/sketch_sep28a
```

How can I move this location to my documents folder. In Arduino preferences, I have also changed the location of sketch, still it does save in above location.

Comment: I appreciate this is a issue with the Arduino IDE, but you might get more help on a Mac forum.

Comment: Hi @CodeGorilla, I am afraid that goes a bit beyond the IDE - I am experiencing the same issue with `arduino-cli`

Answer (score -1):

- Download the latest IDE from Arduino.cc
- Drag your Arduino application icon to the trash.
- Open up terminal and type `rm -r ~/Library/Arduino15`
- Delete the Arduino folder in your Documents folder for good measure
- Drag the newly downloaded Arduino application to your application folder and see how it goes from a clean install.

Failing that PlatformIO IMO is a much better IDE for developing on these platforms : http://platformio.org/

Comment: isn't the "Arduino folder in your Documents folder" the place where OP might have saved his precious projects?